# How to show dialog for getting value of parameter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

How can I show a dialog for getting values of parameters in SQL Server?

For example there are two parameters in a query, `@Name` and `@Family`; right now, I get two dialogs instead of using SET.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50);
SET @Name = 'Chad';

SELECT *   
FROM tbl 
WHERE Name = @Name;
```

I mean that instead of set the value of `@Name` using `SET @Name = 'Chad'`, I'd like to show a dialog which gets the value for that parameter from user and then sets it to `@Name`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this `show two dialog instead of using SET.
`

Comment: Example: Q: Declare @Name Vacrahr(50); SET @Name='Chad'; Select * from tbl where Name=@Name;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want [template parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179334(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE Name = <Name, VARCHAR(50),'default_value'>;
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/template/replace-template-parameters):

> The Specify Values for Template Parameters dialog is a grid with three columns. The Parameter and Type columns are read-only and cannot be changed. Review the contents of the Value column, and change any of the defaults to values appropriate for your implementation.
>
> To use this dialog box, you must have parameters in your script enclosed in angle brackets (< >) in the format: **parameter_name, data_type, default_value**.

When you run your code you will get windows like:
[image]

<sup>Image source: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/blogbits/david.atkinson/Using-a-SQL-Prompt-snippet-for-easy-data_D810/TemplateParams_thumb_3.png</sup>

Comment: It doesn’t show up when you run the code. It shows up when you press ctrl, shift and m.

Comment: @MartinSmith  yes, to be precise it won't work when hit F5. By run the code I've meant icon `ab->ac`